# SSRS Convert string 12 hour time to 24 hour time

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

In my data set I have a string value 1:43 PM.  I would like to convert this to 13:34.  I have set the text box property to this
[image]

But it does not make any change the time still shows as 1:43 PM.  IS there anyway to make this conversion?

Comment: if i remember right, you need `HH:MM:ss` for 24 hour time

Comment: You can't use date and time formats to "convert a string". You will have to convert your string to a time value before you can apply a date/time format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your time is coming in as a string so you would need to convert the string before you could get the time.

```
=CDATE("1:43 PM")

=CDATE(Fields!TIME_FIELD.Value)
```

and then your format property will format it to the desired result.